# Sound made by a cellphone during dialing

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

**What’s the sound made by a cellphone during ‘dialing’ called?**

When a cellphone makes a notification sound, we say “chiming of the cellphone” like that how would we describe ‘dialing’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Beep"  (as a noun or a verb)

There are technical terms like "keypad tone", but I doubt many people who are not telephone engineers would use them. Casually you would say the phone was beeping.

> I knew she was calling someone, because I could hear the beeps coming from her phone.

While I'd understand "chiming of a cellphone", it's not typical. You'd normally say "The phone is ringing".

"Cellphone" seems very dated to me, "phone" or "mobile" is much more common.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the possible answers is **[keypad tone](https://www.samsung.com/in/support/mobile-devices/how-to-enable-dialing-keypad-tone-in-samsung-galaxy-grand2/)**. That is if you are typing.

If you are referring to what you hear while you are waiting for the call to be answered, it's **[caller ringback tone](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/24223/caller-ringback-tone-rbt)**.

> In North America, a standard caller RBT is repeated as a two-second tone with a four-second pause between tones. In other countries, like the UK, Ireland, Australia and New Zealand, it is a double ring. As mobile technology has advanced, the caller RBT term has become more synonymous with a customized RBT that replaces a standard caller RBT.

Comment: Or possibly the 'simulated' ringing sound, which would generally just be referred to as "the phone ringing" even though you it wouldn't normally be the same sound.

Comment: Isn’t ringback tone nothing but just a music which is set by the receiver to keep the call entertained?

Comment: Is ‘ringback tone’ an actual term like ‘chiming of cellphone’ which is used to describe notification sound?

Comment: From the link: "In North America, a standard caller RBT is repeated as a two-second tone with a four-second pause between tones. In other countries, like the UK, Ireland, Australia and New Zealand, it is a double ring. As mobile technology has advanced, the caller RBT term has become more synonymous with a customized RBT that replaces a standard caller RBT."

Answer (score 1):

We may say **phone line trilling**.

Comment: The OP himself answers the question!

Comment: Yes,  we encourage self-learners!  But can you make this a better answer?  Don't just answer the question.  Please explain how and why.  What experience or knowledge are you using here in your answer?   This is particularly important for self answered questions.

Comment: @JamesK that’s the only possible term I could think of. It’s just that I only knew the name of that term and I was looking forward to getting a more appropriate term for the same.

Comment: I think it can also be 'key-tone'. This link may be referred to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad. Of course, beep-sound is one of the best options.

Comment: @Rampillai A ‘key-tone’ is a different thing, it’s a sound made by the keypad buttons when pressed. I asked for the ‘beep sound’ made by phones while dialing.